# How to write VCL components with C++ Builder XE10 (Seattle) and CLANG

Tags: c++, clang, c++builder, vcl

In my application I need to catch the OnDrawCell-event of the TDBGrid component (which is not available/visible by default).
Therefore I created a new component (named TDBGridHack) as a descendant of TDBGrid.

Header file:

```
#ifndef DBGridHackH
#define DBGridHackH

#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.DBGrids.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Grids.hpp>

class PACKAGE TDBGridHack : public TDBGrid
{
    private:
        Vcl::Grids::TDrawCellEvent FOnDrawCell;
    public:
        __fastcall TDBGridHack(TComponent* Owner);
        __published:
            __property Vcl::Grids::TDrawCellEvent OnDrawCell = {read=FOnDrawCell, write=FOnDrawCell};
            virtual void __fastcall DrawCell(int ACol, int ARow, const TRect& ARect, TGridDrawState AState);
};

#endif
```

Source file:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "DBGridHack.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Durch ValidCtrCheck wird sichergestellt, dass die erstellen Komponenten
// keine virtuellen Funktionen haben.
//

static inline void ValidCtrCheck(TDBGridHack *)
{
    new TDBGridHack(NULL);
}

__fastcall TDBGridHack::TDBGridHack(TComponent* Owner)
    : TDBGrid(Owner)
{
}

void __fastcall TDBGridHack::DrawCell(int ACol, int ARow, const TRect& ARect, TGridDrawState AState)
{
    TDBGrid::DrawCell(ACol, ARow, ARect, AState);

    if ( FOnDrawCell )
    {
        FOnDrawCell( this, ACol, ARow, ARect, AState );
    }
}

namespace Dbgridhack
{
    void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
    {
        TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TDBGridHack)};
        RegisterComponents(L"Hack", classes, 0);
    }
}
```

The code compiled well and in my test application everything worked as expected:

- I inserted the newly created DBGridHack from the component palette onto the MainForm
- Double-Clicked the OnDrawCell in the event-palette

...and got the following code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::DBGridHack1DrawCell(TObject *Sender, int ACol, int ARow,
          const TRect &Rect, TGridDrawState State)
{
    // do something here....
}
```

So far - so good, but:
the real final application where I planned to use this component is built with the clang compiler.

Changing the TestApplication's compiler to CLANG (32bit) throws a linker error: "unresolved external **__InitExceptBlockLDTC**...".

So I changed the compiler settings of the BPL also to CLANG (32bit).
- Installing the component worked, but the component itself disppeared from the palette.

Then I've added the "-tP" option as mentioned here:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Release_Notes#Additional_Options_for_BCC32C_to_Generate_a_Package

Results:

- The component returned back to the palette.
- It was also possible to place the grid onto the TestApplications form.

...but Double-Clicking the OnDrawCell event created the following broken code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::DBGridHack1DrawCell(Variant , int , int , Variant &, Variant )
{

}
```

Now I am a little bit stuck.
What is the correct way to create VCL components for usage with the CLANG compiler?

best regards
Herwig

My setup is: Embarcadero C++ Builder XE10 Seattle (without update subscription package) on MS Windows 10.

Comment: What do you need to do in `OnDrawCell` that can't be done in the standard `TDBGrid.OnDrawColumnCell` and `TDBGrid.OnDrawDataCell` events?  Regarding the `__InitExceptBlockLDTC` error, the clang compiler has issues when Runtime Packages are enabled, so you usually have to turn that off, which is not a good thing when you are creating your own package that wants to share RTL packages with the calling app. You may have to stick with the classic 32-bit compiler, or even switch to Delphi, when writing custom packages.

Comment: I need to do modifiactions (e.g. draw icons) into the header row. AFAIK this can't be done by OnDrawDataCell. If I had the Delphi personality I'd do that, but I only have C++ Builder. The last version I've got a licensed version of Delphi is XE2...

Comment: The RTL/VCL is written in Delphi, so C++Builder includes a Delphi compiler, even if you don't have the Delphi personality. You can use `.pas` files in a C++ project. Or use the command line Delphi compiler.

Comment: Still same problem with Tokyo C++ 10.2.1, so finally we cannot use Clang since it doesn't support custom packages.